# Behavior showing an Interstitial Ad on an activity using a SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-intent, admob, interstitial

I'm using, among other views, a [`SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) in my main activity.

The class which extends the [`SurfaceView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) implements also the [`SurfaceHolder.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback) with the callback methods:

- surfaceCreated
- surfaceChanged
- surfaceDestroyed

I'm also using the [Google Admob Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) to show [`Interstitial`](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) ads.

Now I experience two different behavior starting a child activity started by me and showing an interstitial ad started using the Google Admob SDK.

---

1. Behavior starting a child activity by myself

I use

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SettingsActivity.class));
```

which calls the [`SurfaceHolder.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback) methods `surfaceDestroyed` and `surfaceCreated` once I return to the main activity.

---

2. Behavior starting a [interstitial ad](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd) from the Google Admob SDK

I use

```
if(_myInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
{
  _myInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

which calls the [`SurfaceHolder.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback) methods `surfaceChanged` and `surfaceChanged` once I return to the main activity. Yes, it calls the `surfaceChanged` twice.

With the Android Studio "Layout Inspector" I see that the started interstitial ad is also an Activity (`com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity`). So I'm really wondering what is when I start my own activities.

[image: Google AdActivity]

---

Can someone explain how does Google achieve this behavior that only the `surfaceChanged` methods are called?

Maybe I miss an Intent flag on my `startActivity` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've figured out. If someone can tell me more accurate information about it I'll be happy to accept a "full" explaining answer.

> Can someone explain how does Google achieve this behavior that only the `surfaceChanged` methods are called?

**Answer:** The `surfaceChanged` method is called because the Interstitial Ad is displayed as full screen. I can trigger the same behavior following [Googles description](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive).

I strongly assume that the `AdActivity` is not actually an activity (I'm happy if someone proofs me wrong) which is why `surfaceDestroyed` and `surfaceCreated` are not called when the Interstitial Ad is shown.